Application error is coming in heroku, for N8N one click deploy, after deploying
According to the n8n documentation of one click deploy to heroku, I clicked the button, named the app and set the required fields. later I generated SSL using ACM and the status is green. but in the logs H10 is coming. I talked with the officials as well, they said there is no problem in heroku end, H10 comes because there is some problem with your app code. But I haven't done anything by myself. So what is causing the Application error?
Later I changed the config credentials using this command seeing the credentials available in Postgresql database.
Command :  heroku config:set DB_HOST=your_host_name DB_USER=your_username DB_NAME=your_database_name -a myapp    but still it's not working.
some of the part of logs i'm sharing:
Error: There was an error initializing DB
2024-05-15T11:18:34.273404+00:00 app[web.1]: DatabaseError: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "52.211.32.179", user "USER", database "MYDATABASE", no encryption
2024-05-15T11:18:36.342475+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2024-05-15T11:18:36.365967+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=myapp-1cd4d7fe9452.herokuapp.com request_id=MY_REQUEST_ID fwd="157.40.241.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2024-05-15T11:18:39.029215+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=myapp-1cd4d7fe9452.herokuapp.com request_id=MY_REQUEST_ID fwd="157.40.241.248" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
I have changed the request id for here with actual.
Can anyone tell me, is there some way to fix this application error. or this method isn't working anymore. so what method else to see I can easily deploy the n8n.
